# JavaScript: Breaking up sentences into smaller chunks

Tags: javascript, regex, math

**Goal**

So, I'm trying to break up large sentences into smaller ones that are between a certain threshold.

**Base Idea**

Write a function to find the best number for this regex: `.{1,20}(?:\s|$)`

**Issue**

But my sentences are various lengths, so I have a problem just using a static number. I need to calculate the correct number to use instead of "20" in the regex above.

**Criteria**

The number found should optimize to get the biggest sentences possible with 165 characters being the upper limit and 70 being the lower limit.

All sentences passed to this function will be higher than 165 characters in length.

**Examples**

So, let's say I pass it a sentence with 166 characters. This should return 2 new sentences of roughly 83 characters each.

I think the number found would get passed to this regex: `.{1,83}(?:\s|$)` to produce 2 sentences with no remainder.

Result: `['first half of the sentence', 'second half of the sentence']`

If I pass it a 400 character sentence, it will return 4 shortened sentences of around 100 characters each.

Any thoughts would help.

Comment: So, you start at character 165, and back up until you find a space.  That's the break spot.

Comment: @TimRoberts I think I'm missing something. If I start at 165 and the string is 180, this will give me 1 string that is within the threshold and one string that is not. I need both within the threshold of 70 min to 165 max

Comment: you would be much better off with a function/loop/parser than a regexp here. if you must, then use a function replacement instead of a string replacement, then you can put your logic in the function. I would imagine that looks something like chunkCount = Math.ceil(x.length / maxLen). Then start on the big string at pos max, and walk left until you find a good spot to break. then crawl right max spaces and repeat.

Comment: what if, you make a loop from 70 to 165, and divide the length of the original sentence by the numbers you get from the loop. Whichever divides it perfectly (or with the least remainder) will be used to split your sentence.

Comment: I agree with dandavis. A parser would be a much better fit in this scenario

Comment: If 165 is the upper limit, 70 the lower limit and you want to produce the longest segments, why in a 400 character sentence you want 4 chunks with ~100 and not not 3 chunks with ~133 characters? I have played with it [here at ideone.com (JS demo)](https://ideone.com/2VA56y), guess the math part can be optimized!

Comment: @bobblebubble Agreed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so here is what I went with using TypeScript:

```
const MAX_LENGTH = 165;
const MIN_LENGTH = 70;

function createChunks(
  remainingText: string,
  bestBreak: number,
  chunks: string[]
): void {
  if (remainingText.length > bestBreak) {

    // find space closest to bestBreak point
    for (let i = bestBreak; i < remainingText.length; i++) {
      const charCode = remainingText.charCodeAt(i);

      // once found, push chunk to array
      if (charCode === 32) {
        chunks.push(remainingText.substring(0, i));

        // get the remaining text
        remainingText = remainingText.substring(i, remainingText.length + 1);
      }
    }
  } else {
    chunks.push(remainingText);
  }
}

function getChunks(text: string, bestBreak: number): string[] {
  const chunks: string[] = [];
  let remainingText = text;

  createChunks(remainingText, bestBreak, chunks);

  return chunks;
}

function createShorterSentences(text: string): string[] {
  const sentenceLength = text.length;
  let remainder = MAX_LENGTH,
    bestBreak = MAX_LENGTH;

  // find best breaking point
  for (let i = MIN_LENGTH; i < MAX_LENGTH; i++) {
    const currRemainder = sentenceLength % i;

    if (currRemainder <= remainder) {
      remainder = currRemainder;
      bestBreak = i;
    }
  }

  return getChunks(text, bestBreak);
}
```